# LDAP connection response server unavailable

Tags: c#, ldap

I am trying to authenticate with LDAP with various code snippet but always getting ldap server unavailable.
While same connection when i tried to connect with LDAP browser then it worked.
http://btechintegrator.com/index.php/2020/01/22/free-online-cloud-ldap/

[image]

[image]

Any idea what specific C# code snippet i should use to connect and authenticate

tried following

```
try
            {
                LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("LDAP://www.btechldap.com", 1389));
                con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                con.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallBack);
                con.Credential = new NetworkCredential("cn=readonlybind,ou=admins,dc=btechsample,dc=com", "btechpass");
                con.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                con.Bind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }


 try
            {
                string username = "developer";
                string password = "developer_pass";
                string filter = "(&(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))" +
                     "sAMAccountName=username)";
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                LdapDirectoryIdentifier directoryIdentifier =
                   new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("LDAP://shihadeh.intern/cn=developer,ou=admins,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern", 389, true, false);
                using (LdapConnection connection =
                   new LdapConnection(directoryIdentifier, credentials, AuthType.Basic))
                {
                    connection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 90);
                    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                    connection.Bind();
                    //SearchRequest search =
                    //    new SearchRequest(username, filter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Base, "mail");
                    //SearchResponse response = connection.SendRequest(search) as SearchResponse;
                    //foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine(entry.Attributes["mail"][0]);
                    //}
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
```

I am able to connect via Java following code. needed equivalent .net one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "ldap://localhost:389";
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=developer,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "developer_pass");

        try {
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            System.out.println("connected");
            System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());

            // do something useful with the context...

            ctx.close();

        } catch (AuthenticationNotSupportedException ex) {
            System.out.println("The authentication is not supported by the server");
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            System.out.println("incorrect password or username");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.out.println("error when trying to create the context");
        }
    System.console().readLine();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you showing 3 different hostnames in the above examples? I see `www.btechldap.com`, `shihadeh.intern` and `localhost`. I think you should try the C# example with localhost.

Comment: I have tried to connect with two implementation.  one is local container running at 127.0.0.1:389 with domain name shihadeh.intern.  (https://github.com/wshihadeh/ldap_server) other one is a publically available ldap server (http://btechintegrator.com/index.php/2020/01/22/free-online-cloud-ldap/) i am able to connect both from LDAP browser and java code. but .net doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes I had are the `ldap://` in the server path address

The following code works:

```
try
{
    // don't add LDAP://, the protocol is already known ...
    LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("127.0.0.1:389");
    // notice we don't use the domain here
    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(
          "cn=developer,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern",
          "developer_pass");

    // Apache Directory Server uses LDAPv3
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

    // 10389 is the plain port, no ssl needed
    //ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    // ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

    // let's not negotiate, only Basic is supported
    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yes, like I said, you do not need the LDAP url syntax. But good that it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapdirectoryidentifier.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_DirectoryServices_Protocols_LdapDirectoryIdentifier__ctor_System_String___System_Int32_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_), the `LdapDirectoryIdentifier` constructor method you are using requires an array of LDAP server *hostnames* or *ip addresses*, not the ldap url syntax.

Try this:

```
string[] servers = {"shihadeh.intern"}
LdapDirectoryIdentifier directoryIdentifier =
         new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(servers, 389, true, false);
```

Comment: there were multiple overloads. but no effect and same error when used above one